# Query to return all duplicates for all rows

Tags: mysql

I want to return each row in the table, along with the id of each other row that has a duplicate value in a specific column.  I can get all duplicates easily enough, but I need to return more data

Example Data:

```
--------------------------------
| Firstname   | Lastname  | ID |
--------------------------------
| John        | Smith     |  1 |
--------------------------------
| Jane        | Smith     |  2 |
--------------------------------
| Bill        | Smith     |  3 |
--------------------------------
```

If I match on Lastname, I would like to return

```
ID    Firstname   Lastname   dup_Fname  dup_Lname dup_id
1     John        Smith      Jane       Smith     2
1     John        Smith      Bill       Smith     3
2     Jane        Smith      John       Smith     1
2     Jane        Smith      Bill       Smith     3
3     Bill        Smith      John       Smith     1
2     Bill        Smith      Jane       Smith     2
```

I really only need to return IDs, but included the names in the example for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by joining the table with itself using different alias names:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.FirstName, T1.LastName,
       T2.FirstName as dup_FName, T2.LastName as dup_LName, T2.ID as dup_id
FROM TableName T1, TableName T2
WHERE T1.ID <> T2.ID
ORDER BY T1.ID,T2.ID
```

Result:

```
ID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    DUP_FNAME   DUP_LNAME   DUP_ID
1   John        Smith       Jane        Smith       2
1   John        Smith       Bill        Smith       3
2   Jane        Smith       John        Smith       1
2   Jane        Smith       Bill        Smith       3
3   Bill        Smith       John        Smith       1
3   Bill        Smith       Jane        Smith       2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3da76/2).

Comment: Thanks, I was overthinking the solution.  One small tweak though to match on lastname.  Add t1.LastName = t2.LastName condition